# C++11/14: Wrap a function if it exists

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, enable-if

I'd like to write a `wrapper` class (very much a proxy) that aggregates an object, and forwards member function calls to it.  That's trivial in C++11/14 using variadic templates and `decltype`.  My problem is that there are member functions that the wrapped object may or may not support.

I came up with a solution that seems to work, however, it looks extremely clumsy, and I'm looking for simplifications.  In particular I'm afraid this might be extremely costly at compile time (there are *many* functions to wrap).  This clumsiness comes from the need to specify the return type of the function without leaving to decltype something on which to choke.

Would someone have a better idea?

The following piece of code is also available [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6cd2ba4f64c1a8a).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

/// Compute the result type of a member function call, or void if invalid.
#define RESULT_OF(Name)                                                 \
  template <typename T>                                                 \
  class result_impl_ ## Name                                            \
  {                                                                     \
  public:                                                               \
    /* Type made public to please Clang 3.7. */                         \
    template <typename C, typename... Args>                             \
      static auto Type(void*)                                           \
      -> decltype(std::declval<C>().Name(std::declval<Args>()...));     \
                                                                        \
    template <typename, typename...>                                    \
    static void Type(...);                                              \
                                                                        \
    template <typename... Args>                                         \
      using type = decltype(Type<T, Args...>(0));                       \
  };                                                                    \
                                                                        \
  template <typename T, typename... Args>                               \
  using maybe_result_of_ ## Name                                        \
    = typename result_impl_ ## Name<T>::template type<Args...>

/// Forward to function Name, if is exists.
#define FORWARD(Name)                                                   \
  template <typename... Args>                                           \
  auto Name(Args&&... args)                                             \
    -> maybe_result_of_ ## Name<Base, Args...>                          \
  {                                                                     \
    return base.Name(std::forward<Args>(args)...);                      \
  }

#define DEFINE(Name)                            \
  RESULT_OF(Name);                              \
  FORWARD(Name)


template <typename Base>
struct wrapper
{
  Base base;
  DEFINE(foo);
  DEFINE(bar);
};


#define PING()                                  \
  std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'
struct foo_no_bar
{
  void foo(int)           const { PING(); }
  int foo(double)         const { PING(); return 1; }
  int foo(double, double) const { PING(); return 1; }
};

struct foo_and_bar
{
  void foo() const { PING(); }
  void bar()       { PING(); }
};

int main()
{
  wrapper<foo_and_bar> f;
  f.foo();
  f.bar();
  wrapper<foo_no_bar> b;
  b.foo(1);
  b.foo(1.0);
  b.foo(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: @Jamboree Would you have a live example to show what you mean and how it works?

Comment: @akim `auto` follows the rules of template argument deduction. `decltype(auto)` follows the rules of decltype.

Comment: if you are comfortable with using `operator->` instead of `.` notation when calling member-functions from your wrapper this is very trivial to implement. would you be interested in such solution?

Comment: @remyabel Yes, indeed, I am aware of that.  However `auto` and `decltype(auto)` are not SFINAE friendly, so I can't see how that would work.  Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp Hey!  I never thought about that!  You are right that it might be a very interesting alternative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I took a bunch of your work you do in a macro, and took it out.

`can_apply_t` takes a `template<class...>class` and a pack of types, and is true if the types can be applied to the template legally.

```
template<class...>struct voider { using type=void; };
template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template<class...>struct types{ using type=types; };

namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class types, class=void>
  struct can_apply : std::false_type {};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, types<Ts...>, void_t< Z<Ts...> > >:
    std::true_type
  {};
}

template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply_t = details::can_apply<Z, types<Ts...>>;
```

Then we get to replacements for your macros.  I decouple method names from object names, and do it in a few steps.  These steps can be done *outside* of the class for each method:

```
#define CALL_METHOD_RESULT(Name, Method) \
template<class Sig, class=void> \
struct Name {}; \
template<class C, class...Ts> \
struct Name< C(Ts...), void_t< \
  decltype( std::declval<C>().Method(std::declval<Ts>()...) ) \
>> { \
  using type = decltype( std::declval<C>().Method(std::declval<Ts>()...) ); \
}; \
template<class Sig> \
using Name ## _t = typename Name< Sig >::type
```

The above defines `Name_t` which is a traits class that takes a `Object(Args...)` and tells you the return type of `Object.Method(Args...)` in a SFINAE friendly context.

Next, we build a `can_call_Method` helper template using this, and the above `can_apply_t`:

```
#define CAN_CALL_METHOD( Method ) \
CALL_METHOD_RESULT( call_ ## Method, Method ); \
template<class Sig> \
using can_call_ ## Method = can_apply_t< call_ ## Method ## _t, Sig >
```

Next, a `FORWARD` macro that generates a pair of overloads for `Name`, one of which calls `target.Method(Args...)` where `Target target`, and the other one is only considered if the first is not and explicitly `=delete`s the call to generate a possibly better error message.

```
/// Forward to function Name, if is exists.
#define FORWARD(Name, Method, Target, target) \
  template <class... Args> \
  auto Name(Args&&... args) \
  -> call_ ## Method ## _t<Target(Args...)> \
  { \
    return target.Method(std::forward<Args>(args)...); \
  } \
  template <class...Args> \
  std::enable_if_t<!can_call_ ## Method <Target(Args...)>{}> \
  Name ( Args&&...) = delete
```

Now we wrap up the above in a similar DEFINE macro.  Here we recouple everything back to the one name:

```
#define DEFINE(Name) \
  CAN_CALL_METHOD(Name); \
  FORWARD(Name, Name, Base, base)
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53ecb7867b45ad29)

We can also make the `=delete` method do something else, such as nothing, if you want.

Note, however, if we omit the entire `=delete` method, we can actually do controlled dispatch between two sub-objects (even with priority!)

An easier way to do all of this is of course

```
Base* operator->(){ return &base; }  
Base const* operator->()const{ return &base; }
```

which lets you access `Base` as `wrapper->foo(whatever)`.  It does expose *everything* about `Base`.